# What is a proper HTTP status code that server returns when it limits total number of connections?

Tags: c, sockets, http

I have made a simple HTTP server that listens to socket connections. The server code limits total number of connections that it can hold simultaneously.

So, I have these lines:

```
do {
 new_fd = accept(lfd, NULL, NULL);
 nfds += 1;
 ...
 if(nfds + 1 > ntotal){ // connection limit exceeded
  set_headers( new_fd, /* HTTP status code here */ );
  /* close socket after error had been sent */
 }
}while(1);
```

In this situation I'm interested with HTTP status code that server should send before closing socket.

Comment: I usually return 503, but to each their own.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/359096

Comment: @Gaurav That is too many connections per user. Not overall. This should be in the 5xx range.

Comment: @WhozCraig Status code 503 seems legit to me. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *[this link](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)*, it appears *503* is the appropriate HTTP status code to send for an overloaded server.

> 10.5.4 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is currently unable to handle the request ***due to a
>   temporary overloading*** or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.
>
> ```
>   Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a
>   server must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish
>   to simply refuse the connection.
> ```

(***bold*** emphasis mine)

Comment: At this time I use to send error in headers and close connection right afterwards.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко  Note the comment about looking for (or  providing) an estimated _retry-after_ if the duration of the condition is known...

Comment: From the task I'm facing, I know that, connections to the server will be long-lasting. About an hour or even whole day. Donno is it makes sense to send retry after 1 day.

Comment: LOL, no, I suppose not.  Note also the very last section of the post.  You do not have to send anything just because _503_ exists.  Its up to you.

Comment: The problem is, I need output that user sees to be more responsive. So that web page will not wait for 2 minutes just to show an error. Still I think there will be no chance that users hit high watermark of connections.

Comment: Any HTTP response other than to HEAD or CONNECT can carry body content.  You can send a 503 response and include a human-friendly text message or html page in the message body, and a browser will usually display it to the user.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Doing it for every error server sends. BTW Chromium does not display all of messages(HTTP body response), some of messages get missed somehow. Browser just go blank page. But if i do "debugging mode", error shows up. Do you know why it may happen?

Comment: @Ярослав Машко-  There is a conversation _[HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/202244/show-http-error-details-in-google-chrome)_ about your Chromium question.  (BTW, _[superuser](https://superuser.com/)_ is frequented by IT related experts, for questions like this.)